# Get the value of a lookup column and pass to a child display page

Tags: spservices

Need to get the value of a lookup column and pass it to a child list display in a new page 
Use SP Services? has this ever been done not finding any info. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Creating a SharePoint Parent/Child List Relationship–No SPD Version](http://www.sharepointhillbilly.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=4)

The blog post explains the following in short:

> **1) Edit the default Display Form for the Issue list**
>  a. Add Time list to the page
>  b. Set up web part connection between the
>   Issue Display Form and the Time list
>  c. Write a script that
>   overwrites the “Add new item” link and passes in the Issue’s ID as a
>   Query String parameter
>
> **2) Modify the default New Item Form for the Time list and add a script that:**
>  a) Sets the value of the IssueID lookup field
>   b) hides the “Issue ID” field to stop meddling users and their darn
>   dogs from changing it

Comment: Yes, already have that, issue is I am using Parent, child , grandchild. In the Parent I have user lookup fields and need to pass that value from the Parent to the Grandchild display page.

Comment: Tried using this method, issue is it only pulls the query string and not the user record. Any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: Once you get the query string you can use SPServices/JSOM to query the record on page load.

Comment: Yes, understood but the ID in the string is the ID of the child list not the Parent, remember I am using Parent Child Grandchild relationships